# How to add an additional loader in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I new in Angular, I try to import a .js file to my app.component.ts, the file is part of an npm package

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ListenerScroll } from '../utils/listener-scroll';

@Component({...});
```

but I have this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:28)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| export class ListenerScroll {
>       static listenerScrollAdded = false;
|       static listenerScroll = [];
|
```

I understand that static properties are not available in all browsers so I have to "convert" the .js file, in webpack you can add babel and it converts the modern language into one that browsers can read, how could something be done similar in angular?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: As can be seen from the error, Angular does use Webpack behind the scenes. The standard way to add additional configuration (incl. loaders) is via the `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` package. It's reasonably simple to use, and your case is a rather common one - you need additional loaders for a particular file extension. Don't think it's necessary to post a whole answer detailing how to set up Babel for JS files in Angular, as the process would be mostly the same as anywhere else, and there are plenty of resources available. Hope this points you in the right direction!